# Remove timestamp and display full date in x axis, echarts4R

Tags: r, plot, line, echarts

```
data_ <- data.frame(
  x = c(7, 20, 12, 15),
  y = as.Date(c('2019-01-28', '2019-01-29', '2019-01-30', '2019-01-31'))
)

data_ %>%
  e_charts(y) %>%
  e_line(x)
```

In the above plot timestamps between dates are appearing. How can I remove the timestamp and show full date in x axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type of the x-axis to category.

```
data_ %>%
  e_charts(y) %>%
  e_line(x) %>%
  e_x_axis(type='category')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An option is to convert to `character` class after `arrange` the rows by the 'y' (Date column)

```
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)
data_ %>%
    arrange(y) %>% 
    mutate(y = as.character(y)) %>% 
    e_charts(y) %>%
    e_line(x)
```

-output

[image]